# How is it possible to create a data frame (using pandas) from variables without having to assign values again?

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose we have these variables with assigned values:

```
x_minimum=18
x_maximum=60
y_minimum=30 
y_maximum=50
```

How can I create a python data frame (using pandas) with the variables only without having to assign the values again in the data frame?

Such as that the values (x_minimum, x_maximum, y_minimum,y_maximum) are the attributes with the values (18,60,30,50) as entries in the row of the data frame.

Comment: Data frame? That sounds like you're using some kind of third-party library, like pandas. In that case, you really should mention it in your question and add a tag accordingly, if one exists.

Comment: Seems like you found the button! I added the tag to make easier for people to find your question.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
pd.DataFrame([[x_minimum, x_maximum, y_minimum, y_maximum]], columns=['x_minimum', 'x_maximum', 'y_minimum', 'y_maximum'])
```

Output:

```
   x_minimum  x_maximum  y_minimum  y_maximum
0         18         60         30         50
```

Or maybe this:

```
pd.DataFrame([x_minimum, x_maximum, y_minimum, y_maximum], index=['x_minimum', 'x_maximum', 'y_minimum', 'y_maximum'], columns=['value'])
```

Output:

```
           value
x_minimum     18
x_maximum     60
y_minimum     30
y_maximum     50
```

Comment: I suppose the OP is looking for the second method